# ReactQuery useInfiniteQuery is only returning the first page of data

Tags: reactjs, react-query, tanstack

I'm converting some code to use TanStack ReactQuery `useInfiniteQuery` hook.

Everything is working, EXCEPT when loading new data, instead of the *next* page's results the 1st page's data gets duplicated.

Calling the `fetchNextPage` method triggers a re-render but returns the 1st page's cached data instead of fetching new data. i.e. my `gqlListOrdersByAccountIdAndDate()` function is only called once. The `getNextPageParam` function is correctly returning the next token.

I thought perhaps I need to add the value from pageParam/nextToken to the queryKey so it'll be unique, but absolutely none of the examples I've seen do that. Not sure why I keep getting the cached data instead of fetching the next page.

Here's the component:

```js
import { useInfiniteQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query"
import { gqlListOrdersByAccountIdAndDate } from "../utils/gqlListOrdersByAccountIdAndDate"

const Orders = ({ accountId }: { accountId: string }) => {

  const listOrders = async ({ pageParam = null }) =>
    gqlListOrdersByAccountIdAndDate(accountId, pageParam)

  const { error, isLoading, fetchNextPage, data } = useInfiniteQuery({
    queryKey: ['orders', accountId],
    queryFn: listOrders,
    getNextPageParam: (lastPage, pages) => lastPage.data?.ordersByAccountIdAndDate?.nextToken
  })

  const orders = data?.pages.flatMap(p => p.data?.ordersByAccountIdAndDate?.items)

  return <InfiniteTable items={orders} fetchMore={fetchNextPage} />
}

export default Orders
```

The query is just GQL, but I've artificially limited it to only return 5 results for testing.

```js
export async function gqlListOrdersByAccountIdAndDate(accountOrdersId: string, nextPage: string | null) {
  console.log('gqlListOrdersByAccountIdAndDate', accountOrdersId, nextPage)
  return API.graphql<GraphQLQuery<OrdersByAccountIdAndDateQuery>>(
    graphqlOperation(
      ordersByAccountIdAndDate,
      { accountOrdersId, nextToken: null, sortDirection: 'DESC', limit: 5 })
  )
}
```

Comment: You're passing `nextToken: null` to your GraphQL operation, meaning it will only ever return the first page of data regardless of what `nextPage` is?

Comment: That was an evil typo! Thanks for spotting it.